# Is it all right to put the whole <head> tag into template_part file?

Tags: menus, templates, navigation, headers

I need to have more than one headers so this looks as a good idea but I'm not sure if it is valid. If so, what am I supposed to name a file? I named it head.php so far.

Example:

```
<html>
  <!-- <head> tag -->
  <?php get_template_part('head.php'); ?>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav> Navigation </nav>
    <h1> Page title </h1>
```

Comment: But generally you can name your template parts anything you want, as long as you write code to include them into other templates.

Comment: By header I mean <header> tag which in my case includes Page Title and Navigation.

Comment: Then yes, you can split up the HTML any way that's useful.

Comment: Oh, OK, so you did mean the <head> tag? (So when you said multiple <header> tags you meant multiple header templates?) But yes, you can do that fine. Although normally there's only a few lines in the <head> tag anyway - most of it is generated by the call to wp_head().

Comment: Thank you very much